# Does giving someone credit in the Admin panel issue the credit through Paypal?

Tags: paypal, creditmemo, refund

```
Magento 1.9.1
Paypal Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout)
```

If I give somebody a credit on the back-end (in the Admin panel) - does that go trough on Paypal automatically?

Comment: What sort of credit you are doing? Are you creating a credit memo, or using a store credit module? Also what sort of Paypal module are you using ?

Comment: @William Tran Paypal Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout). I am looking for any which way to issue a credit back from the Admin panel via Paypal....What is a better way to do that - via creating a credit memo or using a store credit module? Now that I read that - I didn't install any additional modules....

Comment: The easiest way to check is by going to invoice, clicking on "Credit memo" button and if the credit memo form has "Refund" button it means it will be refunded online via paypal, if you see only "Refund offline" then it cannot do online refund. Note that when you click "Credit memo" from order view you will only see offline refund button as Magento does not know which invoice to use for refund.

Answer (score 0):

Magento CE 1.9.1 doesn't come with a Store Credit functionality. So I think what you are talking about is creating a credit memo for refund. In that cause check the Paypal module that you are using if it allow online refund.

Comment: Thank you supersieutrum. The Paypal module I am using is "Paypal Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout)". Does that automatically issue a credit to the customer via Paypal after I go through setting up a credit memo in the Magento Admin panel?